# Is there any Mockito-like framework for java application (not under JUnit/Testing environment)?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing a tool (**not for Testing purpose**) based on some existing code (class A, module B here) which I can't touch, I want to mock their behaviours.

I am trying to find something like Mockito for my java application but not under JUnit/Testing environment, or a solution which can make Mockito work out of JUnit/Testing environment.

Here is class A:

```
public final class A{  // I can't touch this class, and I can't touch module B where A is called
    public static String getType(String name){
        ... // DataBase access
    }
}
```

Here is my application:

```
public class myApp{
    public Object compute(String name){
        // execute module B's code, where A is widely called
        return computedObject;
    }
}
```

I don't want to access database ihn my aplication, I just want to mock A's method in my java application like Mockito does in JUnit, but I am not able to make it work out of JUnit or find similar framework for java application.

If I use Mockito, then I will have

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)  // does this mean Mockito only works under Testing environment?
public class myApp{ 
    @Test
    public Object compute(String name){
        // mock A           
        // call code in module B
        return computedObject;
    }
}
```

but I can not call a test method and get its return value from my java application which is not JUnit, JUnitCore can only execute all tests and can't return the value of some Test method.

> I need do exactly the same thing as Mockito but not under Testing
>   environment, I can't modify the class A neither the module B, and in
>   the future I may need to mock the creation of object/mock static
>   method... (same functionality as Mockito), but I don't want to rewrite
>   a Mockito for java application since it will be too costly, so a
>   similar framework working out of JUnit would be great.

Could anyone give me any idea?

EDIT :

I think my use case is quite common, and such a framework would be quite helpful in some cases.

Why there isn't such framework, did I miss something or I made some mistake?

Comment: Maybe AspectJ could help you with this, or implement a proxy pattern behind that class

Comment: Why not just implement an interface, or use composition? Or even implement a `ServiceProvider`?

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you use Mockito itself? It doesn't *require* JUnit. If you want to mock an object with it in your program, then do it.

Comment: @fge, because I can not touch the class A, it is something existing already.

Comment: @Guillaume F, because I got some problems when I try to use Mockito not with JUnit, plus Mockito is a JUnit framework which makes me think it can only work with JUnit, I'll retry.

Comment: Mockito is not linked to JUnit at all; for instance, I use it with TestNG

Comment: @fge , have you ever used Mockito out of Testing environment, I mean for a normal java application? because I need to add "@PrepareForTest(A.class)" to use mock class A and this is for Testing environment.

Comment: You don't neeed to, there are static methods (Mockito.mock(), etc etc); but I think you are facing an XY problem. I'm sure there are other ways to achieve what you want than to resort to this rather drastic measure.

Comment: Simply use an in-memory database such as [h2 with the memory jdbc url](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases) instead of the real one for development.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, the DB is out of my control and it is so large, I don't want to access any DB in my application.

Comment: @seaguest That's EXACTLY why I suggested using a dummy, in-memory DB during development...

Comment: Mockito should be quite "useable" outside of test environment.  If you're using maven, specify in the pom.xml that its scope is "compile" and it will be available at normal runtime, instead of just during unit tests. GL!

Answer (score 2):

If it is not an option to modify your "module B" (as described in the comments of your question) you could use a byte code instrumentation library like [ByteBuddy](http://bytebuddy.net/), [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) or [CGLIB](https://github.com/cglib/cglib). These libraries allow you to rewrite the byte code of your methods at runtime and are typically used in java agents.

(Btw, Mockito does exactly that. It uses ByteBuddy to instrument your classes)

Comment: I don't want to rewrite a framework like Mockito, because I may need to mock static method/mock a normal method/mock constructor.... in the future, it will be too complicated for solving my pb, is there any existent framework does the same thing Mockito but not under Testing environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you write the tool

> "I am writing a tool which has a dependency on module B"

then you can remove the dependency to B by using an Interface:

```
public interface IData {
  String getType(String a)
}
```

and within B:

```
public class BDataAcess implements IData {
    public String getData(String a) {
       return A.getType();
    }
}
```

and use it in productive code this way

```
IDataAcess dataAcess = new BDataAcess();
dataAcess.getData("money");
```

in unit test you replace the dataAcess with your own IDataAcess.

```
application.setDataAcess(new MyTestDataAcess());
```

where MyTestDataAcess is implemented in your unit test folder.

You don't need any special lib for that, just pure java.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the pb I have is that I can't touch class A, neither module B where A is called

Comment: If you can't touch B then it is not your job to test B. Design for testability has to be done while developping the src, not afterwards.