# Can we Mock any object or class but not in Junit

Tags: java, rest, mocking, mockito, jmockit

Which mock framework can we use to mock a class or its object.
We usually use mocking framework while implementing junit test cases, but how can i mock a class/its's object not in any test case class but a normal class.

Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any Mockito-like framework for java application (not under JUnit/Testing environment)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945506/is-there-any-mockito-like-framework-for-java-application-not-under-junit-testin)

Comment: let me open a big secret - junit test case is normal class, the same as any other

Comment: Yes i agree, but i want to use mock framework in java application , not in junit or any testing environment

Answer (score 0):

While mock-frameworks are normally done only in test code, that's not a requirement.  You could certainly import your favorite mocking framework as a compile (not test) dependency, and then in any src/main/java class, you would be able to constuct mocks in the normal manner (e.g. @Mock etc).

Why you would do that, I don't know.  And therein lies a much more intersting question.  Realize mock-frameworks operate via reflection and sometimes by byte-code manipulation.  That poses some concern for production-quality code, but now you have it in mainline source.  Depending on what you are REALLY trying to accomplish, there might be better ways - e.g. de-encapsulation, AoP, stubs, etc.